# Use input as parameters for a function called by a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have used a dictionary to allow a user to input something, but the next problem is using a second word as a parameter for the called function. At the moment, I have:

```
def moveSouth():
    Player.makeMove("south")
def moveNorth():
    Player.makeMove("north")
def moveEast():
    Player.makeMove("east")
def moveWest():
    Player.makeMove("west")

function_dict = {'move south':moveSouth, 'wait':wait, 'sleep':sleep,
                 'move north':moveNorth, 'move':move, 'look':look,
                 'move east':moveEast,
                 'move west':moveWest}
```

And to get the input:

```
command = input("> ")
command = command.lower()
try:
   function_dict[command]()
except KeyError:
   i = random.randint(0,3)
   print(responses[i])
```

However, rather than having to have 4 different functions to make a move, I was hoping there would be a way so that when the user inputs "move south", it uses the first word to call the function, and then 'south' as a parameter for the direction in that function.

Comment: Why do you define `moveWest` and others, then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` the input and then pass each part in separately.

```
command = input("> ")
user_input = command.lower().split()
command = user_input[0]
if len(user_input) > 1:
    parameter = user_input[1]
    function_dict[command](parameter)
else:
    function_dict[command]()
```

Comment: @PierreGM Exactly how I feel this morning. Added a check.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for this, managed to be able to use function_dict[command]() as well, kudos :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
command = input("> ")
command_parts = command.lower().split(" ")
try:
   if len(command_parts) == 2 and command_parts[0] == "move":
       Player.makeMove(command_parts[1])
   else:
       function_dict[command_parts[0]]()
except KeyError:
   i = random.randint(0,3)
   print(responses[i])
```

Essentially I just try to split the input by a space and decide the type of the command by the first part (*move*, *wait*, *look* ...). The second part is used as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of command line processing, you can easily use the `cmd` module. It allows you to create commands by creating methods like `do_<cmd>`, with the remainder of the line as arguments.

In case you cannot use the `cmd` module, you will have to parse the command line yourself. You can do this using `command.split()`.